# Can you run KVC functions in Xcode Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, kvc

I'm following a tutorial on KVC and KVO when I attempted to enter the code into a playground however it wouldn't run.  I received the error "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException".  I even tried to create a single app application and entered the information into a viewController to see what happens and it still wouldn't build which provided the error that the object wasn't key coding compliant.  I'd really like to see this work, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


//this is a reference object which means when it is copied, it will copy a reference to the same instance and not a brand new value like a value type does
class Student: NSObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var gradeLevel: Int = 0
}


let seat1 = Student()
seat1.setValue("Kelly", forKey: "name")
```

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with using a playground. You get the error no matter where you run it: *"'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<SomeApp.Student 0x100f26e60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not the playground. Your issue is that to use the Objective-C KVC mechanism, you need to mark the property with `@objc`.

```
class Student: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String = ""
    var gradeLevel: Int = 0
}
```

Adding that will fix the crash.

Comment: I thought subclassing from NSObject would handle interfacing with the Objective-C runtime?  Is that not the case or has it ever been the case?

Comment: Thank you so much! I was reading <2015 - Cocoa Programming for OS X 5th> and got this problem too.